# Is a contained in [a,a]?

Tags: general-topology

Is $a\in[a,a]\subset\mathbb{R}$? I learned the natural topology on $\mathbb{R}$ as the family of sets $U$ such that for all $x\in U$, there exists some positive $\varepsilon\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $(x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)\subset U$. With this definition, I think $(a,a)$ is empty. But then I know that $\bar{\emptyset}=\emptyset$ because the empty set is closed.

However, in my calculus classes (or maybe I'm misremembering), I think I was told that $a$ is contained in $[a,a]$, which also makes sense intuitively ($a\leq a\leq a$). Could someone confirm if this is true? Is there another topology where $[a,a]$ is nonempty?

Comment: Well, what is your definition of $[a,a]$?

Comment: The closure of (a, a) with the natural topology I mentioned. Predicting your response, is there a topology on R where open intervals are still open sets and closed intervals closed but [a, a] is nonempty?

Comment: $[a,a]$ is not the same as $\overline{(a,a)}$, at least not with respect to the standard definitions.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Could you explain how they're different? I'm new to topology.

Comment: The usual definition of $[a,a]$ is that it is the (degenerate) interval $\{ x \in \mathbb{R} : a \le x \le a\} = \{a\}$.  This has nothing to do with topology---this is simply the usual definition of the notation.  On the other hand, $\overline{(a,b)}$ is the closure of $(a,a)$ with respect to some topology.  In the standard topology (which is the one you've described), $\overline{(a,b)} = [a,b]$ when $a < b$, but $[a,a] = \{a\} \ne \varnothing = \overline{(a,a)}$.

Comment: I see; thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is all about *definitions*.

> **Definition 1:** Let $a \le b$ be real numbers.  The *open interval* $(a,b)$ is the set
> $$ (a,b) = \{x \in \mathbb{R} : a < x < b \}, $$
> and the *closed interval* $[a,b]$ is the set
> $$ [a,b] = \{ x \in \mathbb{R} : a \le x \le b\}. $$

Observe that if $a = b$, then
$$ (a,a) = \{ x\in\mathbb{R} : a < x < a \} = \varnothing
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
[a,a] = \{ x\in\mathbb{R} : a\le x\le a\} = \{a\}. $$

Note that, while these definitions contain the words "open" and "closed", these words are not being used in a topological sense (at least, not yet).

> **Definition 2:** A set $U\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is (*topologically*) *open* if for each $x\in U$, there exists some $\varepsilon > 0$ such that
> $$ (x-\varepsilon, x+\varepsilon) \subseteq U. $$
> A set $K$ is (*topologically*) *closed* if $\mathbb{R}\setminus K$ is open.  If $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is any set, the *closure* $A$ is the set
> $$ \overline{A} = \{x\in \mathbb{R} : \forall\varepsilon>0, A \cap (x-\varepsilon, x+\varepsilon) \ne \varnothing \}. $$
> That is, the closure of a set $A$ consists of all of the points which are "arbitrarily close" to $x$.

Every open interval (with respect to Definition 1) is a topologically open set (with respect to Definition 2).  Similarly, every closed interval is a topologically closed set.  This is true even for degenerate intervals:  $(a,a) = \varnothing$ is topologically open, and $[a,a] = \{a\}$ is topologically closed.

In general, the closure of an open interval $(a,b)$ is the closed interval $[a,b]$ but, as has been observed in the question, this result is not true when $a = b$.  This can be directly observed by noting that
$$ \overline{(a,a)} = \overline{\varnothing} = \varnothing \ne \{a\} = [a,a]. $$
It is perhaps worth noting that $\overline{\varnothing}$ is closed:  $\mathbb{R}\setminus \varnothing = \mathbb{R}$, which is an open set.

Answer (score 2):

$[a,a]=\{a\}$ is a degenerate interval consisting of a singleton.

It's true that $\overline{(a,b)}= [a,b]$ where $a<b$, since $a$ and $b$ are limit points of $(a,b)$.

However, in the degenerate case, $\overline{(a,a)}\ne [a,a]$, because $(a,a)=\emptyset$, and any neighborhood containing $a$ does not intersect $(a,a)$.